# obtain data from remote computers using autoit

Tags: autoit

I have been maintaining a program written in batch. I want to write a replacement program using autoit.
The program is downloaded to the desktop of remote computers and prints out a log of the scan results in notepad on the desktop.
I want it to cover windows XP-vista-7-8-8.1-10. At the moment it does not cover 8-8.1 or 10.

This is the printout:

Results of my test version 001

Windows 7  x86 Service Pack 1 ---- (shows in brackets if service pack is out of date)

(UAC) --- shows if UAC is on or disabled.

Internet Explorer----(shows if out of date)

`Antivirus/Firewall Check:`
Windows Firewall Enabled!

Panda Free Antivirus
 WMI entry may not exist for antivirus; attempting automatic update.

`Anti-malware/Other Utilities Check:`
 CCleaner

Java 8 Update 31   (Java version out of Date!)

Adobe Flash Player     17.0.0.188
 Adobe Reader XI

Mozilla Firefox (38.0.5)
Thunderbird (38)

`System Health check`
 Total Fragmentation on Drive C: 2%

````````````````````End of Log``````````````````````

Comment: What is your question? Do you need a AutoIt script that does the same but also for Windows 8-10?

Comment: Yes I do desperately, please. I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: This is doable but I don’t think you are going to get a complete answer because it would take a day or two for someone to write the complete AutoIt script.

Answer (score 0):

So this is possible. To get versions of files(like java and firefox) I think you can use `FileGetVersion`

To get if windows filewall is enabled you have to read the registry. This key might be a little bit different depending on your system but the one for me was this one

```
RegRead("HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\DomainProfile\", "EnableFirewall")
```

These two macros should be usefull to determine OS specific information that you request

```
@OSType
@OSVersion
```

UAC can also be read from the registry and as with the firewall it might depend on your system but for me this was the registry:

```
RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", "EnableLUA")
```

Im not quite sure what the Total Fragmentation means so I am not sure how you can get this.

You should be able to compose a txt file with all this information. You should be able to find examples of autoit code that transfers text files just by searching here on stackoverflow or on google.